# External commands in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have various files of extensions .cpp stored on the server. When user clicks on the compile button, I should run gcc command passing the absolute path of the file to gcc compiler and then show the user the output of the file.
How can i do that???

Comment: I think that question is rather about ruby than about ruby-on-rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kernel.system](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html) may the command that you are looking for: it calls a system process. For example:

```
if (system("gcc ..."))
  @output_to_show = %x['./compiled']
end
```

Assuming that your server is in Linux/UNIX, it would be good to separate the compile&execute process from the website server in order to reduce the security risks (by creating a new user just for this purpose). Or can you trust the content of the cpp-Files?

Comment: -
"You may want to run theses processes under another user-id, just to be sure they don't overwrite some of your hard-gained code files etc. ..."....I could not understand that. Can you alaborate a bit.

Comment: - Could you explain the %x['./compiled'] part in your code. How can i get the output/ errors in the compilation process

Comment: While system() only returns the success (or not) of the command, %x[] returns the outpout of stdout (see linked article: http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html).